# Bison simple postfix calculator using union with struct

Tags: struct, bison, unions

Im making a simple calculator that prints postfix to learn bison. i could make the postfix part work ,but now i need to do assigments to variables (a-z) tex: a=3+2; should print: a32+=; for example. Im trying modified my working postfix code to be able to read a char too.
If I understand correctly, to be able to put different types in the $$ i need a union and to make the nodes i should use a struct because in my case 'expr' can be a int or a char.
This is my parser:

```
%code requires{
    struct nPtr{
        char *val;
        int num;
    };
}

%union {
    int iValue;
    char sIndex;
    struct nPtr *e;
};

%token PLUS MINUS STAR LPAREN RPAREN NEWLINE DIV ID NUMBER POW EQL
%type <iValue> NUMBER
%type <sIndex> ID
%type <e> expr line

%left PLUS MINUS
%left STAR DIV
%left POW
%left EQL

%%
line : /* empty */ 
     |line expr NEWLINE      { printf("=\n%d\n", $2.num); }
expr : LPAREN expr RPAREN     { $$.num = $2.num; }
     | expr PLUS expr        { $$.num = $1.num + $3.num; printf("+"); }
     | expr MINUS expr        { $$.num = $1.num - $3.num; printf("-"); }
     | expr STAR expr         { $$.num = $1.num * $3.num; printf("*"); }
     | expr DIV expr         { $$.num = $1.num / $3.num; printf("/");}
     | expr POW expr         { $$.num = pow($1.num, $3.num); printf("**");}
     | NUMBER                 { $$.num = $1.num; printf("%d", yylval); }
     | ID EQL expr           { printf("%c", yylval); }
     ;

%%
```

I have this in the lex to handle the "=" and variables

```
"="       { return EQL; }
[a-z]     { yylval.sIndex = strdup(yytext); return ID; }
```

i get and error 
warning empty rule for typed nonterminal and no action
the only answer i found here about that is this:
[Bison warning: Empty rule for typed nonterminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887852/bison-warning-empty-rule-for-typed-nonterminal)
It says to just remove the /* empty */ part in:

```
line: /* empty */
    | line expr NEWLINE { printf("=\n%d\n", $2.num); }
```

when i do  that i get 3 new warnings:

```
warning 3 nonterminal useless in grammar
warning 10 rules useless in grammar
fatal error: start symbol line does not derive any sentence
```

I googled and got some solutions that just gave me other problems, for example.
when i change:

```
line:line expr NEWLINE { printf("=\n%d\n", $2.num); }
```

to

```
line:expr NEWLINE { printf("=\n%d\n", $2.num); }
```

bison works but when i try to run the code in visual studio i get a lot of errors like:

```
left of '.e' must have struct/union type
'pow': too few arguments for call
'=': cannot convert from 'int' to 'YYSTYPE'
```

thats as afar as i got. I cant find a simple example similar to my needs. I just want to make 'expr' be able to read a char and print it. If someone could check my code and recommend some changes . it will be really really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to actually understand what you are asking Bison to do, and what it is telling you when it suggests that your instructions are wrong.

Applying a fix from someone else's problem will only work if they made the same mistake as you did. Just making random changes based on Google searching is neither a very structured way to debug nor to learn a new tool.

Now, what you said was:

```
%type <e> expr line
```

Which means that `expr` and `line` both *produce a value* whose union tag is `e`. (Tag `e` is a pointer to a `struct nPtr`. I doubt that's what you wanted either, but we'll start with the Bison warnings.)

If a non-terminal produces a value, it produce a value in every production. To produce a value, the semantic rule needs to assign a value (of the correct tag-type) to `$$`. For convenience, if there is no semantic action and if `$1` has the correct tag-type, then Bison will provide the default rule `$$ = $1`. (That sentence is not quite correct but it's a useful approximation.) Many people think that you should not actually rely on this default, but I think it's OK as long as you know that it is happening, and have verified that the preconditions are valid.

In your case, you have two productions for `line`. Neither of them assigns a value to `$$`. This might suggest that you didn't really intend for `line` to even have a semantic value, and if we look more closely, we'll see that you never attempt to *use* a semantic value for any instance of the non-terminal `line`. Bison does not, as far as I know, attempt such a detailed code examination, but it is capable of noting that the production:

```
line : /* empty */
```

1. has no semantic action, and
2. does not have any symbols on the right-hand side, so no default action can be constructed.

Consequently, it warns you that there is some circumstance in which `line` will not have its value set. Think of this as the same warning as your C compiler might give you if it notices that a variable you use has never had a value assigned to it.

In this case, as I said, Bison has not noticed that you never use value of `line`. It just assumes that you wouldn't have declared the type of the value if you don't intend to somehow provide a value. You did declare the type, and you never provide a value. So your instructions to Bison were not clear, right?

Now, the solution is not to remove the production. There is no problem with the production, and if you remove it then `line` is left with only one production:

```
line : line expr NEWLINE
```

That's a recursive production, and the recursion can only terminate if there is some other production for `line` which does not recurse. That would be the production `line: %empty`, which you just deleted. So now Bison can see that the non-terminal `line` is *useless*. It is useless because it can never derive any string without non-terminals.

But that's a big problem, because that's the non-terminal your grammar is supposed to recognize. If `line` can't derive any string, then your grammar cannot recognize anything. Also, because `line` is useless, and `expr` is only used by a production in `line` (other than recursive uses), `expr` itself can never actually be used. So it, too, becomes useless. (You can think of this as the equivalent of your C compiler complaining that you have unreachable code.)

So then you attempt to fix the problem by making (the only remaining) rule for `line` non-recursive. Now you have:

```
line : expr NEWLINE
```

That's fine, and it makes `line` useful again. But it does not recognise the language you originally set out to recognise, because it will now only recognise *a single line*. (That is, an `expr` followed by a `NEWLINE`, as the production says.)

I hope you have now figured out that your original problem was not the grammar, which was always correct, but rather the fact that you told Bison that `line` produced a value, but you did not actually do anything to provide that value. In other words, the solution would have been to *not* tell Bison that `line` produces a value. (You could, instead, provide a value for `line` in the semantic rule associated with every production for `line`, but why would you do that if you have no intention of every using that value?)

Now, let's go back to the actual type declarations, to see why the C compiler complains. We can start with a simple one:

```
expr : NUM { $$.num = $1.num; }
```

`$$` refers the the `expr` itself, which is declared as having type tag `e`, which is a `struct nPtr *`. The star is important: it indicates that the semantic value is a *pointer*. In order to get at a field in a struct from a pointer to the struct, you need to use the `->` operator, just like this simple C example:

```
struct nPtr the_value;        /* The actual struct */
struct nPtr *p = &the_value;  /* A pointer to the struct */
p.num = 3;                    /* Error: p is not a struct */
p->num = 3;                   /* Fine. p points to a struct */
                              /* which has a field called num */
(*p).num = 3;                 /* Also fine, means exactly the same thing. */
                              /* But don't write this. p->num is much */
                              /* more readable. */
```

It's also worth noting that in the C example, we had to make sure that `p` was initialised to the address of some actual memory. If we hadn't done that and we attempted to assign something to `p->num`, then we would be trying to poke a value into an undefined address. If you're lucky, that would segfault. Otherwise, it might overwrite anything in your executable.

If any of that was not obvious, please go back to your C textbook and make sure that you understand how C pointers work, before you try to use them.

So, that was the `$$.num` part. The actual statement was

```
$$.num = $1.num;
```

So now lets look at the right-hand side. `$1` refers to a `NUM` which has tag type `iValue`, which is an `int`. An `int` is not a struct and it has no named fields. `$$.num = $1.num` is going to be processed into something like:

```
int i = <some value>;
$$.num = i.num;
```

which is totally meaningless. Here, the compiler will again complain that `iValue` is not a struct, but for a different reason: on the left-hand side, `e` was a pointer to a struct (which is not a struct); on the right-hand side `iValue` is an integer (which is also not a struct).

I hope that gives you some ideas on what you need to do. If in doubt, there are a variety of fully-worked [examples in the Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Examples).